# setTimeout is not getting called

Tags: javascript, html

I have wrapped my function call in a `setTimeout` method like this with for example a 2 second delay. But it is NOT doing anything. It is not causing any delay. 
What have I wrote wrong?

```
onclick="setTimeout(MyOriginalFunction('2004', 'Y', 'M', '12'),2000);"
```

Comment: The argument to `setTimeout` has to be a reference to a function, not a function call itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for passing parameter in setTimeOut function.

```js
function GiveMeCall(name){
alert('Called me '+name);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setTimeout(function(){GiveMeCall('Rahul')},2000);" 
 >click me</button>
```

Please have a look it is getting called. let me know if this is helpful for you.
This SetTimeout function only look for reference of the function.

```js
function MyOriginalFunction(){
alert('Called me');
}
```

```html
<button onclick="setTimeout(MyOriginalFunction,2000);" 
 >click me</button>
```

Comment: what about the parameters for the function? how would you pass those?